# Delete duplicate items in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Sos, Ser
    [1] => Sos, Ser, Pieczarki
    [2] => Sos, Ser, Szynka
    [3] => Sos, Ser, Salami
    [4] => Sos, Ser, Szynka, Pieczarki
    [5] => Sos, Ser, Szynka, Ananas
    [6] => Sos, Ser, Salami, Pieczarki
    [7] => Sos, Ser, Tunczyk, Cebula
)
```

I want to delete duplicates. `array_unique()` doesn't work. Desired result:

```
$result = array('Sos', 'Ser', 'Pieczarki', 'Szynka', 'Salami', 'Ananas','Tunczyk','Cebula');
```

Comment: Can you post the final result array you want?

Comment: i want to only delete dplicates like Sos, Ser, Szynka, Salami from this array

Comment: "Delete" doesn't give 100% clarity here. Do you want these values removed entirely? Do you want to preserve first occurrence? Do you want duplicated values stored in another var?

Comment: Can you show us the expected output of that array?

Comment: $result = array('Sos', 'Ser', 'Pieczarki', Szynka', 'Salami', 'Ananas','Tunczyk','Cebula');

Comment: Maybe an array is not the best data structure for this case. Consider using a hash set or similar.

Comment: I guess, you can use something like this: `$result = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(function($v){return array_map('trim', $v);}, array_map(function($v){return explode(',', $v);}, $source_array_of_strings))));` :D ... It could seems too complex, but it's not... you'll see )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the final array output you want, the code should be something like this:

```
<?php

$original = array("Sos, Ser",
    "Sos, Ser, Pieczarki",
    "Sos, Ser, Szynka",
    "Sos, Ser, Salami",
    "Sos, Ser, Szynka, Pieczarki",
    "Sos, Ser, Szynka, Ananas",
    "Sos, Ser, Salami, Pieczarki",
    "Sos, Ser, Tunczyk, Cebula",
);

$uniques = array();
// Loop over each original string
foreach ($original as $st) {
    // Split at ', ' to extract names from each string
    $names = explode(", ", $st);
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        // Store this name as a key in the uniques array
        $uniques[$name] = 1;
    }
}

$uniques = array_keys($uniques);
print_r($uniques);

/* Output:

Array
(
    [0] => Sos
    [1] => Ser
    [2] => Pieczarki
    [3] => Szynka
    [4] => Salami
    [5] => Ananas
    [6] => Tunczyk
    [7] => Cebula
)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is `$array`.

```
    $all_items = [];

    foreach ($array as $a1) {
        foreach ($a1 as $a2) {
            if (!in_array($a2, $all_items)) {
                $all_items[] = $a2;
            }
        }
    }

    return $all_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of the exploded values and `array_unique()` that:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $value) {
    $result = array_merge($result, explode(', ', $value));
}
$result = array_unique($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array always helps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$aLong = [
    'Sos, Ser',
    'Sos, Ser, Pieczarki',
    'Sos, Ser, Szynka',
    'Sos, Ser, Salami',
    'Sos, Ser, Szynka, Pieczarki',
    'Sos, Ser, Szynka, Ananas',
    'Sos, Ser, Salami, Pieczarki',
    'Sos, Ser, Tunczyk, Cebula',
];

$aTotal = [];
foreach ($aLong as $sSub) {
    foreach (preg_split('/, */', $sSub) as $sWord) {
        if (!in_array($sWord, $aTotal)) {
            $aTotal[] = $sWord;
        }
    }
}

print_r($aTotal);
```